# remove '//' & /*...*/ comments in c file to get preprocessed file using c

Tags: c, comments

this is my program, i am trying to remove single line & multiple line comments...
here i am using command line argument to execute the program
`$./a.out sample.c sample.i` 
i want to remove comments in c file and get the pure c file like it was preprocessed..
while executing my program it gives segmentation fault and it does not removing comments...
any one can try this and tell me where the error is occuring in my program and how to avoid that..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *s=NULL,*p=NULL,*q=NULL;
    int i,size,j;
    if(argc!=3)
    {
    printf("error : improper use of file\n");
    printf("use : ./file <filename.c> <filename.i>\n");
    return;
    }
    fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
    printf("file does not exist\n");
    return;
    }
    fseek(fp,0,2);
    size=ftell(fp)+1;
    rewind(fp);
    s=calloc(1,size);
    fread(s,size-1,1,fp);
    fclose(fp);
    puts(s);
    p=s;
    for(i=0;s[i];i++)
    {
    if(p=strchr(p,'"'))
            {
            p++;
            while(!(p=strchr(p++,'"')));//with in printf("....// .... /*....*/ ..") the comment cant be removed
            i=p-s;
            printf("i=%d\n",i);
            puts(s);
            }
else if(p=strstr(p,"//"))
            {
            while(*p!='\n')
            *p++=' ';
            i=p-s;
            printf("i=%d\n",i);
            puts(s);
            }
    if(p=strstr(p,"/*"))
            {
            j=p-s;
            while(!(p=strstr(p,"*/")))
            p++;
            strcpy(s+j,p+2);
            i=p+2-s;
            printf("i=%d\n",i);
            puts(s);
            }
    }
    puts(s);
    fp=fopen(argv[2],"w");
    size=strlen(s)-1;
    fwrite(s,size,1,fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

here is the sample.c program i want to remove comments from this c file

```
#include<stdio.h>//declaring stdio header file
#include<stdlib.h>/*declaring stdlib header file*/
main()//main function starts
{
    int a,b;//declaring integer variables
    printf("Enter // a & b:");
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);/* taking a & b from std i/p device */
    printf("/* result %d * %d = %d */\n",a,b,a*b);//printing result
}
```

and i want the output should be

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter // a & b:");
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    printf("/* result %d * %d = %d */\n",a,b,a*b);
}
```

Comment: Try using a debugger (like GDB) and finding out exactly where the segfault occurs.  This will help you find the faulty code that you need to fix. Also, if you fix your indentation, people will be far more likely to help you. Hard to read code is a turn off.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this against a test file, it crashes on the line

```
if(p=strchr(p,'"'))
```

The reason is that `strstr` amd `strstr` will return `NULL` if no matching string or character is found, so you *probably* don't want to assign the result back to `p`.

Some nits:

1. There's no reason to read the entire file into memory. That approach doesn't scale, and it just adds that many more things to get wrong.
2. As written, this code isn't going to handle nested comments very well (what will happen if you have a `//` delimited comment embedded within a `/* */` delimited block?).  Nor will it handle escaped `"` characters; for example, if you have a string like `"the quote character is \""`, your quote-handling block will mistakenly assume everything following the third `"` is part of a string literal when it isn't.